# Ubuntu 14.04 stuck on splash screen

Tags: server, screen, plymouth

[image: This is link to screenshot splash booting]

Stuck on splash booting screen and i don't know what the error... ;(

Answer (score 1):

If you suspect that the extra partition is the problem, try boot up from a Ubuntu Live system. I.e., If it boots fine, then the extra partition is not the problem/cause.

And while your Ubuntu Live is booted, try to mount all partitions from your HD, especially the boot partition and the OS partition. Do the mount under 'sudo su -' from the command line, when you can see if anything went wrong, so that you can fix the problem.

While Ubuntu is booting up with a splash screen, hit ESC to see what's actually going on. Pay close attention to the message flied by. Last time my Ubuntu boot up froze on me, it was because of line about 20 lines before the last message, which says something like "Press S to fix the disk" (or maybe "C", can't recall the details)